# How to create a replace regular expression for group every two commas?

Tags: regex, perl

This is the expression that I have:

((.)*(,)){2}

Here is the input:

```
1231,3453453,ewrtewrt,wertwe,rwewer,werewrwe
```

I want the expected output is:

```
1231,3453453,
ewrtewrt,wertwe,
rwewer,werewrwe
```

Comment: grouping every two occurances..what does that mean..

Comment: Every two items he wants to insert a newline.

Comment: What problem are you having? Please show what you have written and describe how it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: your regex looks like ____;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/(,[^,]*,)/$1\n/g
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/NoTbg4)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of regex you should just split by a comma (or whatever your expected delimiter is). Then loop over the items and add the newline every two items.

Answer (score 2):

```
=$ perl -e 'my $q = q{1231,3453453,ewrtewrt,wertwe,rwewer,werewrwe}; $q =~ s/((?:[^,]*,){2})/$1\n/g; print $q'
1231,3453453,
ewrtewrt,wertwe,
rwewer,werewrwe
```

That is the regexp is:

```
s/((?:[^,]*,){2})/$1\n/g
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that counts the commas and inserts newlines at every other one:

```
perl -plwe's/,\K/++$i % 2 || "\n"/eg'
```

Which is to say, find a comma, keep it (`\K`) and insert an evaluated string. The iterator `$i` will be even every second comma, so the expression returns a newline, otherwise nothing. Regex is:

```
s/,\K/++$i % 2 || "\n"/eg
```

It does require a counting variable, which may be a downside.